# iterating through list with 2 variables

Tags: list, loops, iteration

I have this list:

```
list=[0, 0.3, .6, .9, 1.2 ,1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5]
```

how can you iterate through the list to create values for i and j such as these pairs:

`0 / 0.3`

`0.3 / .6`

`.6 / .9`

to the inclusive end of the list ?

I tried:

```
a = iter(list)
for i, j in zip(a, a):
       print(str(i) + " / " + str(j))
```

but the boundaries are not repeated and it does not include the last value of the list

Comment: in which language?

Comment: in python but I think I found it, we have to create another iter object starting at index 1 instead of 0

Answer (score 0):

found it:

```
list=[0, 0.3, .6, .9, 1.2 ,1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5]
a = iter(list)
b = iter(list[1::])
for i, j in zip(a,b):
       print(str(i) + " / " + str(j) )

0 / 0.3
0.3 / 0.6
0.6 / 0.9
0.9 / 1.2
1.2 / 1.5
1.5 / 2
2 / 2.5
2.5 / 3
3 / 3.5
3.5 / 4
4 / 4.5
4.5 / 5
```

Comment: list[1:] is sufficient, save a column